# SSIS: import data from excel to sql server database with file last modified date condition

Tags: sql-server, excel, import, ssis

My goal is to build automatic process, which imports data from multiple xlsx files from certain directory to sql server database in regular phases.

I already created SSIS package, which imports data to sql server database. But everytime if I run this package, all xlsx files data will be inserted, but I would not like to import all data again, I would like to import just those xlsx files again, which have been updated after last import.

Currently my data flow is following:
Excel source > OLE DB Destination which runs inside foreach loop container.

I imagine something like that:
I have to insert last import timestamp with file name into some log table and then have to compare it with the xlsx last modified date. But I do not know how to do it. Hope that someone could provide some step by step instructions.

Comment: check this : https://www.decisivedata.net/blog/how-to-use-last-modified-date-when-importing-data-using-ssis

Comment: The most common way to do this is move your excel file into a different folder one it has been imported. Then you won't import it again. This is much simpler than trying to keep track of it in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.learnmsbitutorials.net/insert-update-data-using-merge-join-ssis.php) will give you step by step answer. 
You need to take care about flat file connection to excel file connection and join based on last modified date column.